# Using Dynamics to find the Net Force of a object upon two other masses acting upon it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

So, I drew a picture..

We have 3 masses in a triangle, obvious they are all attracted together, yet they ask for the Fnet on B. Overall I can do questions like these in linear, yet when it comes to this question is stumped me, would be have like a vector (direction) in the final answer? I honestly don't know were to start. Am I even doing this right? Could someone please explain to me were to continue or what I am doing wrong and guide me though it. Greatly appreciated, thanks!
[image: HelpPlease]

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Fair enough, do you guys have an area to post them? I read though your article and it does not seem to have a solid awnser for its "up to debate". I understand its not a high level physics question but to me its still over my head at this level. I did use the homework and exercises tag, I also did describe were I couldnt continue and the general term of dynamics is over my head sometimes so I thought maybe others wouldnt mind :( Sorry..

Comment: There is not currently a homework help site associated with StackExchange for physics and every proposal on [area51.se] ends up being closed due to lack of interest. And AFAICT, there is no debate on HW questions; asking "Am I doing this right?" isn't a concept.

Comment: Well some people replied so to my knowledge some people dont mind doing it. Personally I understand why you think like such but when it comes down to a topic and generally people putting a format in, exampling the entire topic on how to post questions of such and including the "homework" tag I dont understand why even having the tag there in the first place.

Comment: Just like in every other facet of life, there are those that ignore rules set up by others. Some do it because they don't care for rules, others do it because they're ignorant of the rules; either way, just because someone answered doesn't mean it's not against the rules. There have been posts on the Meta site about eliminating the homework tag, but so far they've not been accepted.

Comment: So to my knowledge then since the homework tag has not been accepted to be removed its still in use, along side with the topic on how to post these questions. Am I correct or were did I go wrong.

Comment: The HW policy, as stated in the 1st link I gave, is that you ask about the *concept* that arose during your HW that is causing you to not complete the assignment and **not** "How do I do this?" or "Is this right?"

Comment: The concept of dynamics when it comes to gravitational force is what arose my question. I guess I could edit the question to adhere to the lines of "The concept of gravitational forces acting upon 3 objects in a triangle (dynamics)" Would that be more acceptable, alongside with removing the numbers and such? Im just trying to figure this out man. Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: For what its worth, I don't think this question should be closed, at least not for the reason stated. It's clear that LostAtPhysics showed effort to solve the problem, so it shouldn't be closed for that reason. However, you could object that there is no concept singled out as the topic of the question, but I would say there is: The question says (v2) "Overall I can do questions like these in linear, yet when it comes to this question is stumped me, would be have like a vector (direction) in the final answer?" ...

Comment: From this I gathered that the main source of confusion was how to add forces acting in different directions to get the net force. Looking at the picture of his work supports this conclusion. Therefore I would say his question is really just about that concept. Now you could say that we should only allow questions when the asker himself is able to identify the specific concept he is having trouble with, but I think that will leave out a lot of potential questions. I think as long as the asker makes a good effort to narrow the scope of the question as much as they can, then its specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you pretty well understand how to find the pairwise forces and you are just having trouble adding them to get the net force. Since the forces are vectors, you need to add them like vectors. I assume this is difficult to imagine because you are just learning what a force is and you are just learning what vector addition is.

So think about something you are more comfortable with. Imagine that you have a vector displacement to the north and another displacement to the east. Now try to add them to get the net (that is, total) displacement. You should get something to the northeast. Now you just apply the same reasoning to the force vectors. The pull to the north adds with the pull to the east to give you a pull to the north east.

As you would find with the displacement, there are two ways of representing this resultant vector. You can give the components along the north and east directions (in which case the picture you gave is already a compelete solution), or you can give the magnitude and direction. I recommend you try to do it both ways.

Another relatively minor point is that you should be more careful about your units.